# Is it currently possible to cross the Sino-Nepal Friendship Bridge from China to Nepal in own 4x4 car?

Tags: china, borders, nepal, land-borders

Apparently the Sino-Nepal Friendship Bridge was closed after 2015 earthquakes.

What is the current status of the crossing? Assuming I get a permit to drive my vehicle in Tibet, with a guide of course, I need some way to get with my truck out of Tibet to Nepal or India.

If it is not open now, what are the chances it will be open in the next 6 months?

Comment: [This May 7, 2016 article](http://www.exploretibet.com/blog/kyirong-border-opened/) states *According to CCTV news in China, the Kyirong border will reopen for third nationality tourists from June 1st*. Kyirong (Gyirong) region seems to be more to the west, I cannot find an exact location (village). ... *both the Chinese and Nepal government have invested to build roads to Kyirong and find it as the alternative border by concerning safety, distances and many other prospective.*

Comment: The article linked by @JanDoggen precedes a massive landslide caused by monsoon rains in July 2016. As of today, August 2016, the border is still closed and it is impossible to say when it will open, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update:

### The border crossing between Tibet and Nepal has re-opened as of September 2017.

[Detailed post by The Land of Snows.](http://www.thelandofsnows.com/tibet-nepal-border-open/)

Old post:
**It is currently impossible to cross the border.**
(unless you hold a Chinese or Nepali passport.)

Recent info from [The Land of Snows](http://www.thelandofsnows.com/) (which I have praised in [an unrelated answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/74783/32134)) as [of 27 July 2016 (updated 23 Jan 2017):](http://www.thelandofsnows.com/tibet-nepal-overland-border-closed/)

> Since the April 2015 Nepal Earthquake, the Tibet Nepal border has been closed to foreign travelers. [...]
>   **At this time, it is impossible to say when this border will reopen.** I expect the border will remain closed until at least summer 2017....maybe longer.

In a more recent comment as of 27 May 2017, Lobsang writes

> The border is only open to Chinese and Nepali passport holders and is CLOSED to all other nationalities. The border remains closed and no one knows when it will reopen.

And this is still all that can be said. You may have gotten hopeful by [this May 7, 2016 report](http://www.exploretibet.com/blog/kyirong-border-opened/) linked in [a comment by @JanDoggen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74386/is-it-currently-possible-to-cross-the-sino-nepal-friendship-bridge-from-china-to#comment164013_74386) above - however that precedes a massive rockslide just past the Chinese border buildings following heavy rains in July 2016 at Kyirong.

You should give a good look to [the above linked post](http://www.thelandofsnows.com/tibet-nepal-overland-border-closed/) and especially the sections "When will the Tibet-Nepal Border Reopen?" and "What Areas Are Closed?"
The author of the website/blog promises to update that article once there are changes and post [updates on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/thelandofsnows/) as well.

The old border in Zhangmu seems to be a ghost town by now and apparently there are no plans to re-open the border. While residents claim the street condition on the Nepal side is as before the earthquake, there is still the occasional (fatal) boulder that comes down, as reported in [this 8 months old article](https://nepalitimes.atavist.com/bordering-on-helplessness).

Comment: I can add that the road is definitely not in the same condition as before. Now (I was there in April) the part north of Bahrabise is only possible in a 4wd with lots of construction work in progress. Though much of the constructions appear to be hydroelectrical project. Before (when I crossed the border in 2010) it was a very good asphalt road with very heavy freight traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the update about the re-opening.  You might also wish to update [your answer about overland travel from Myanmar to Nepal as well](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/78901/31165), though I suspect that the route via India you recommend there would still be the easiest.