# Are there any tool/sites I can use to plan my route?

Tags: online-resources, india, planning, russia

I am planning to ride to Moscow next year from Calcutta, India.
I am not able to figure out which route I should take. I heard that you have to go via Myanmar, China, Mongolia and finally Russia.

Is there any tool/site I can use to plan my route (like GoogleMaps)?

Comment: The train border crossing from Mongolia into Irkutsk can be difficult without some knowledge of Russian, but from Irkutsk it's a single train in to Moscow and tools are not necessary.

Comment: We had a similar question a while back, where OP wanted to go to China from India. Moscow would be on the way: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85446/is-it-possible-to-travel-between-india-and-china-by-rail/85452#85452

Comment: Or, if you are willing to travel parts by road, not train, you can go the other way around, via Myanmar to China.

Comment: actually my question is completely by road, the question was edited to rail and I dont know how to edit it back! I will figure out from Myanmar to China first

Comment: @hangar18 Please be specific- by ride you mean bicycle, motorbike, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't met any universal generic solution for a train trip, unless much powerfull than Google maps. But if you need some specific info about Russian trains, here we go.

Most popular travel site to planning a trip is [tutu.ru](https://www.tutu.ru/) (in Russian), where you can find a first version of your trip via bus, train or plane. However, in English there is on Trains part of it.

For example, you can find a complete schedule for [trains between Moscow and Irkutsk](https://www.tutu.travel/poezda/rasp_d.php?nnst1=2054000&nnst2=2000000), with a complete route and station schedule for each of them (e.g., this is a [google map for train `Route 003З Beijing → Moscow`](https://www.tutu.travel/poezda/view_d.php?np=46e77f0c)). This is a good start for finding a train operating over Russia, yet still not a perfect planning tool as it barely knows something outside the Russia.

Other thing that you can give a try is a [RZD official site](http://pass.rzd.ru/main-pass/public/en), main carrier in trains industry in Russia. There you can find a lowest prices for tickets, but the problem with planning outside the Russia persists. Other popular choice is [OZON](https://www.ozon.travel), but it's an reseller and have their site only in Russian.

PS: A couple of years ago [I asked a question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/16/19) regarding such tool for whole Europe, you can investigate that too, maybe those sites know something about Asia trains too.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways from Ulaanbaatar, Mongolia to Irkutsk Russia.

[By Air](https://www.amicusmongolia.com/trip/tours-travel-to-mongolia-from-irkutsk-baikal-lake-russia.html):
There are direct flights from IRKUTSK to ULAANBAATAR: 
Irkutsk – Ulaanbaatar - Irkutsk by AeroMongolia
Frequency: 4 times in a week (Mon, Wed, Fri and Sun)
Valid: 15 May - 31 Aug, 2017

[By train](https://www.amicusmongolia.com/trans-mongolian-train-railway.html): 
The journey from Ulaanbaatar to Irkutsk takes around 24 hours with fast train and 35 hours with daily overnight train . From the Lake Baikal’s remote shores to Mongolian steppes, you can start your adventure at any of these three completely different cultures.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.rome2rio.com/

I find to be a pretty good supplement to google maps.
It tells you different methods, price estimates and links you to where to buy.

Sometimes the options are incomplete but it works.