# Lhasa to Kathmandu by bus

Tags: visas, china, buses, nepal, tibet

I am planning to go to China for 3 months. The next country I would jump into ideally would be Nepal from Tibet, because next I would go India.

As I understand Tibet is now accessible by train from China, so this bit should be easy. However after the earthquake roads were damaged and a trip by bus to Kathmandu is showing conflicting information. [Some claim that you can outright buy a ticket](http://www.tibettour.org/nepal-tibet/way-to-kathmandu.html), others that it's not possible...

**Is it possible to travel from Tibet to Kathmandu by bus? Can I cross the border overland all by myself without tours and such and get visa at the border there?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've read somewhere [can't find it now] that the Gyirong border crossing is now open to foreigners. On the other side of the border, you can get a 15- or 30-day Nepalese visa on the spot. You'll need to bring an ID photo, and USD or RMB.

Note: going to Tibet requires a travel permit, separate from the Chinese visa, which can only be acquired via an accredited travel agency. It requires to give the details of your trip, and make bookings ahead of travel. Once over the border in Nepal, you're free to do what you please.

Comment: Quick and good info on the visa, +1. For the border crossing, please refer to this source: http://www.thelandofsnows.com/tibet-nepal-border-open/ and [my answer here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/74386/32134), which I am about to update.